# How are ARIMA in sample predictions of pmdarima scaled?

Tags: python, time-series, forecasting, arima, pyramid-arima

I performed a time series forecast using `auto_arima` from the pmdarima package. I know that this package is based on the statsmodel SARIMAX package.

Using the command: `fit.predict_in_sample(ARIMA_input, dynamic=None)`, gives  results that are scaled/normalized around 0. I would like to transform the in sample predictions back this to plot it with my input data. Does anyone know how it is transformed? I searched in the [source code from pmdarima](https://www.alkaline-ml.com/pmdarima/_modules/pmdarima/arima/arima.html#ARIMA.predict_in_sample) but I cannot find anything. Using statsmodel SARIMAX the in sample predictions came in the same scaling as my input.

Note: my data is not seasonal so I just use an ARIMA with the statsmodel SARIMAX.

Moreover, if I use the order given by the `auto_arima` fit from pmdarima and use it with statsmodel SARIMAX, I get different forecast results (pmdarima's forecast is very plausible and SARIMAX's is just a straight line). It seems I am not seeing what's done different. Maybe someone of you understands it better and can help me?

If you need more information, I am happy to provide it.